# Delete string in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using local storage to display a list of things and I am just appending on to the end of the localStorage item. How would I delete a certain string from localStorage? They are all in a fib class with a unique id, it would also work if I could just remove the HTML from in between the divs but I don't know how I would actually execute it inside the localStorage item...

Comment: Can you show us an example of the string?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and I don't know how to add code to the post

Comment: Hey,  this might get you an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810141/2601436

Answer (score 2):

Since it's actually HTML, simply turn it *back* into HTML using [`createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment):

```
var yourHTML = getItFromLocalStorage();

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
fragment.firstChild.innerHTML = yourHTML;
var yourElement = fragment.getElementById('your_id');
yourElement.parentNode.removeChild(yourElement);
// fragment.firstChild now contains your HTML *without* the
// element with your_id
```

Comment: This looks just like what I needed. But when I use it it replaces my whole localStorage with [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: If you actually want to store the result back in local storage you'll need to turn it *back* into HTML with `fragment.firstChild.innerHTML`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list of strings and save it in localStorage but you first need to stringify it and parse it back on retrieval. You can create helper functions to save your code/time.

```
function setItem(key, obj){
   localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function getItem(key){
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}

var data = [];
data.push('a');  // ['a']

setItem('data', data);

data = getItem('data'); // ['a']

data.push('b');  // ['a', 'b']

setItem('data', data);

data = getItem('data'); // ['a', 'b']

data.splice(data.indexOf('a'), 1); // ['b']

setItem('data', data);

data = getItem('data'); // ['b']


console.log(data); // ['b']
```

Comment: No mention of json being used in question. Even if it is...this doesn't address what the question is asking

Comment: He asked about localStorage and how you can save a list in localStorage without stringifying and then retrieving array without parsing?

Comment: I replied to this `I'm using local storage to display a list of things and I am just appending on to the end of the localStorage item. How would I delete a certain string from localStorage? `. Is it wrong answer?

Comment: maybe not...but to me personally it doesn't seem relevant. OP clearly knows how to set/get but is focusing on specific nested strings is my perception of problem

Comment: No, OP is simply setting array of strings in localStorage which changes `[ 'a', 'b' ]` to `a, b`.

Comment: Well i guess question isn't as well written as it could be. My interpretation is more inline with what other answer is suggesting....but...that is of course only my interpretation

Comment: If it is not clear then how is your guess superior .. sorry about this all.

Comment: Don't be sorry... the world all evolves around different opinions ...maybe mine is totally wrong and I will happily apologize if so